# MySQL trigger creating error when migrating from DB2

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am trying to convert some `DB2` queries to `MySQL` . I have tried to find some tools to convert the conversion . Unfortunately i din't find any conversions tools and some of the online tools are not converting properly. So i have tried to convert DB2 queries myself to MySQL .

I have started to create 3 trigger queries in MySQL . Unfortunately i am getting some syntax errors . These are the following queries were i migrated from DB2 to MySQL .

**Trigger 1 :**

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_TABLE3 AFTER INSERT ON SAMPLE_TABLE4
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO LICENSE_REVISION(LICENSE, LICENSE_REV) VALUES (NEW.ID, (NEXT VALUE FOR REVISION));
  END;
```

Here i am getting syntax error

```
right syntax to use near 'VALUE FOR REVISION));
  END' at line 9
```

I think the problem due to `NEXT VALUE FOR`  .

**Question 1 :**

Is it any `NEXT VALUE FOR` alternative for MySQL ?

**In trigger 2** , i am doing

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE OF SUPPORT__SERVER_UPS ON SETTINGS
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    FOR d AS SELECT ID AS D_ID FROM DOMAIN
    DO UPDATE DOMAIN_REVISION DR SET DR.SERVER_DOMAIN_REV = (NEXT VALUE FOR REVISION) WHERE DR.DOMAIN = D_ID;
    END FOR;
  END;
```

and getting error :

```
right syntax to use near 'OF SUPPORT__SERVER_UPS ON SETTINGS
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EAC' at line 6
```

i think  the problem is  `AFTER UPDATE OF` with column and i am suspecting `FOR d AS` line 4 and `BEGIN ATOMIC` too .

**Question 2 :**

1. Can i use `AFTER UPDATE OF` with column in MySQL ? and any mistakes
   in `FOR d AS` line no 4 and `BEGIN ATOMIC` line 3 .
2. if i have use multiple column values like

trigger :

```
  CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_4 AFTER UPDATE OF IPV4_FIRST, IPV4, IPV4_MASK, IPV6_FIRST, IPV6, IPV6_MASK ON VIRTUAL_NETWORK
          FOR EACH ROW
          BEGIN
          FOR d AS SELECT DOMAIN AS D_ID FROM DOMAIN_VIRTUAL_NETWORK WHERE VIRTUAL_NETWORK=NEW.ID
            DO UPDATE DOMAIN_REVISION DR SET DR.CLIENT_NETWORK_REV = (NEXT VALUE FOR REVISION) WHERE DR.DOMAIN = D_ID;
            END FOR;
          END;
```

How can i approach this problem ? Should i use like this

```
IF NEW.a <> OLD.a or NEW.b <> OLD.b ?
```

I am beginner in this and i want to help to migrate . I know these are syntax problem and not valid questions . Please help or suggestion .

**Update :**

I have tried with `last_insert_id` and `CURSOR` . This is the working code now :

```
  CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON SETTINGS
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT ID AS D_ID FROM DOMAIN;
  IF NEW.SUPPORT__SERVER_UPS <=> OLD.SUPPORT__SERVER_UPS THEN
  open my_cursor; 
  my_loop: loop
    FETCH my_cursor INTO D_ID;
    UPDATE DOMAIN_REVISION DR SET DR.SERVER_DOMAIN_REV = (last_insert_id()) WHERE DR.DOMAIN = D_ID;
    end loop my_loop; 
    close my_cursor;
   END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR REVISION` looks like it replaceable with `SELECT MAX(REVISION) + 1 FROM [table]`

Comment: Thanks  . I will try it now . Any suggestion for other query ? FYI : I am using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sequences

MySQL doesn't have sequence objects. `NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence>` is not supported in MySQL.

There's an awkward workaround to simulate a sequence by creating a single table that you increment every time you want a new value.

```
mysql> create table sequence (id int not null primary key );
mysql> insert into sequence values (0);
mysql> update sequence set id = last_insert_id(id+1);
mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
```

But every time you would use `NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence>` you would repeat the last two steps above. The last_insert_id() function in MySQL is more or less like DB2's `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()`. Read full docs on last_insert_id() function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

## Column triggers

MySQL trigger declaration syntax is like

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON SETTINGS
FOR EACH ROW ...
```

MySQL supports no "OF" clause. That's used in DB2 for triggering on the update of specific columns, but MySQL doesn't support triggers on specific columns.

## Loops

The `FOR d AS SELECT ...` loop construct is not supported by MySQL. If you need to do a loop, you need to learn about CURSOR syntax. See examples at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: Thanks for valuable information !!!! . I have one query . If MySQL doesn't support triggers on specific columns , how can i write that functionality? Is it any other methods to achieve that functionality ?

Comment: Also can i achieve this functionality with condition for column in trigger  like `if NEW.column1 <=> OLD.column1 THEN` ?

Comment: The trigger will fire on UPDATE if any column changes (like a DB2 trigger if you omit the `ON <column>` clause). So yes, you would have to add `IF/THEN` statements in the trigger body.

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestions and time . I will work on the `IF/THEN `statements  .

Comment: Porting between any two RDBMS products is bound to be a long, complicated process. Despite SQL being an industry standard, each implementation adds a lot of their own custom features and extensions. In particular, the procedure / trigger language for each RDBMS is quite different. So you will probably have to do a lot of reading of manuals, and a lot of testing.

Comment: In general the MySQL manual is quite good, but unfortunately, the sections about procedure / trigger language is really poor.

Comment: yeah . I know . I have to push hard myself to make success . Is there good tools available for conversion ? I have tried some of them but none of them are giving correct conversions . So i have tried to install mysql workbench and trying to do myself .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159923/discussion-between-user2986042-and-bill-karwin).

Comment: I've never heard of any tools to do a conversion between DB2 and MySQL.

Comment: sorry i am new to this . Anyway thanks for valuable suggestions !!

Comment: I have updated my question after adding `CURSOR` and `last_insert_id()` . What i am missing still ? any help

Comment: No `FETCH INTO` for the cursor. Use of LAST_INSERT_ID() makes no sense.

Comment: I have updated now with if condition and can you review once .

Comment: What do you mean by `No FETCH INTO for the cursor` ? I have added by `  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT ID AS D_ID FROM DOMAIN;`

Comment: You apparently didn't read the example on the page I linked to about MySQL cursors.

Comment: I have updated with `    FETCH my_cursor INTO ID;` . Isn't ?

Comment: I am following this https://www.techflirt.com/mysql-cursor-tutorial/ tutorial too . Got good clarification about cursor .